# How to Open Source Swift Code (things to show and hide)

Tags: swift, xcode, git, macos, open-source

Things to publish **and more importantly, things you should hide** when open sourcing an Xcode project. Storing sensitive data securely (configuration files) and using .gitignore

- signatures, API keys, license and serial numbers and other private info
- other files, related to code-signing and sensitive
  data added by Xcode

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: When open sourcing a project (that wasn't meant/properly designed for open sourcing), it may include a serous amount of sensitive info and sometimes it's too late to learn that an API key or license handler was left in the code. The question is what to pay attention to in case of and Xcode project, files and data that needs attention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is a question and answer site and not a place to write tutorials or articles.

Answer (score 0):

Try the obfuscate techniques, which is one way to secure your sensitive data like API keys although this also don't 100% gives guarantee that things are safe but still it added one more layer of non easily breakable security for sensitive data. 
http://www.splinter.com.au/2014/09/16/storing-secret-keys/